# What do you call something that doesn't let you sleep?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Especially a thought.

Example:

> Like last night, I couldn't sleep. This time, however,
>   [...] wasn't my upcoming wedding, but the fact that I was going to get fired
>   tomorrow.

So like a *disturbance*, but one that deprives you from sleep.

Comment: Hah. In business jargon, we often ask "*What* [worries, troubles, concerns, anxieties] *keeps you up at night*?".

Comment: The "monster under my bed".

Comment: Things that go bump in the night.

Comment: So you are getting married right after getting fired! Tough break, pal. Good luck.

Comment: @janoChen - I'd call it 'annoying'

Comment: Simply ***it***.

Comment: @ermanen - No, that should be ***IT***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scientific answer: ***stressor***.

Colloquial answer: ***bugaboo***.

(Either of these will fit in your sentence example. Use with "the".)

Answer (score 1):

This time, however, my **emotional distress** wasn't due to my upcoming wedding, but to the fact that I was going to get fired tomorrow.

or

This time, however, the **distressing factor** wasn't my upcoming wedding, but the fact that I was going to get fired tomorrow.

> - distress (noun) "unhappiness or pain; suffering that affects the mind or body" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distress)
> - distressing (adj) "causing worry or anxiety" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/distressing)

Answer (score 0):

Not disagreeing with Centaurus, but for another approach you could do something along the lines of **sleep-killer**. (There's a quote in The Scottish Play about that.)